# How to Check if strings in an array contain strings from another array

Tags: c#

**Main Question :** 
Ok guys, here is the situation, let's consider 2 string arrays :

```
string foo = { "Roses are #FF0000" , "Violets are #0000FF", "Paint it #000000"}
string bar = { "Guns", "Roses", "Violets"}
```

What is the "fewest code lines" way to retrieve strings in foo containing strings in bar ? 
(i.e, in this case, the 2 first elements of foo)

*Of course I want to avoid doing all the logic "by hand" as I am sure Linq is more efficient with the intersect feature, but I do not know how to use it to perform this precise task.*

**TieBreakers :** 
**1 -** What if foo contains strings that contain more that one element of bar,

```
string foo = { "Roses are #FF0000" , "Violets are #0000FF", "Paint it #000000"}
string bar = { "Roses", "Violets", "are"}
```

And I want to avoid duplicates ?

**2 -** What if I have 2 "bar" arrays that I want to check against one foo array ?
Is it more efficient to merge bar1 and bar2 or to perform the filter with bar1 first and then with bar2 ?

Thanx and have fun answering :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ works well, yes:

```
var mixed = foo.Where(x => bar.Any(y => x.Contains(y));
```

Note that you'll still only see each element of `foo` once, if at all.

If you have multiple `bar` arrays, you can use:

```
var mixed = foo.Where(x => bar1.Concat(bar2)
                               .Any(y => x.Contains(y));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `string` in your description is your teacher's typo,

```
var result=foo.Where(w=>bar.Any(iw=>w.Contains(iw)));
```

I'm not sure what duplicates you mean, that will only show elements in `foo` once no matter how many times they appear in `bar`.

As for the 2nd tie breaker, all you have to do is something like this:

```
var result=foo.Where(w=>bar1.Any(iw=>w.Contains(iw))||bar2.Any(iw=>w.Contains(iw)));
```

Comment: ThanX It works fine but I had to invert `iw=>iw.Contains(w)` to `iw=>w.Contains(wi)` to make it work. Also, I changed the || to && (I've chosen your last syntax proposition because it made sense to me, form a code reading perspective.

Comment: || means in either of them, && means in both of them, I assumed you meant the former.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] foo = new string[] { "Roses are #FF0000", "Violets are #0000FF", "Paint it #000000" };
string[] bar = new string[] { "Guns", "Roses", "Violets" };

var matches = from f in foo
                where bar.Any(b => f.Contains(b))
                select f;

foreach (var m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(m);
```

Comment: Yup this works too (that was the syntax I've been using a couple of years ago) though it's quicker to do without the select and from statements. Thanx.

Comment: @Mika, I prefer the query syntax, especially when the queries grow larger than this in size. I find it more readable.